# On Ubuntu, after 'adding to my asset' from the website. The button used to 'Open in Unity' does not redirect me to UnityHub. How do I solve it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, ubuntu

### Browser does not redirect to UnityHub when clicking button

[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehL3w.jpg)

When trying to use the 'Open in Unity' button a window pops out saying that
no application was found to open link. The windows redirects me to gnome-software
still saying still saying `no application was found`.

[gnome-software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxVPZ.jpg)

I expect UnityHub to open directly from the browser when I
click the button 'Open In Unity' button.

Answer (score 0):

### To redirect browser to UnityHub.

I found file **~/.config/mimeapps.list** and added the following:

```
x-scheme-handler/unityhub=unityHub.desktop
x-scheme-handler/com.unity3d.kharma=unityhub.desktop
```

I found wherever my **unityhub.desktop** file is located. In my case **/usr/share/applications/unityhub.desktop** and added the following:

```
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/unityhub;x-scheme-handler/com.unity3d.kharma;
```

Finally used the command to apply changes:

```bash
update desktop database
```